# OpenVPN: How to reach a specific ip on client network side?

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, forwarding

I have the following constellation:
LOCAL-PC <---> VPN-SERVER <---> VPN-CLIENT <---> TARGET

I want to reach "TARGET" from "LOCAL-PC".
What I did:

a) on "LOCAL-PC": I added a route "route add TARGET_IP MASK 255.255.255.255 VPN_CLIENT_IP

b) activated "IPEnableRouter" on VPN_CLIENT

I would assume now the following hops are done when I ping "TARGET" from "LOCAL_PC".
LOCAL_PC > VPN-SERVER > VPN_CLIENT > TARGET

Unfortunately it doesn't work.
For trial I just added a port-forwarding on "VPN_CLIENT" TO "TARGET" for a specific service.
That works just fine. So I think something does not work with the IP-routing via TUN-Device.

IP-Routing itself is working on "VPN-CLIENT" as I tested it with two local IP-interfaces without a problem.

What am I missing which prevents the TUN-Interface on my vpn-client to forward to target-ip ?

THANKS in advance
mts

REMARK: VPN-Client is a windows-machine, TARGET has VPN_CLIENT as default route.

**EDIT:**

> As Tom pointed out, it is a openVPN routing problem.  That **changes my question**
> as I don't know how to solve my issue:
>
> I want this:
>
> ```
>        LOCAL-PC -> VPN-SERVER
>                    -> VPN_CLIENT1 (10.11.0.6) -> TARGET (10.0.200.1)
>                    -> VPN_CLIENT2 (10.11.0.8) -> TARGET (10.0.200.1)
>                    -> VPN_CLIENT3 (10.11.0.14) -> TARGET (10.0.200.1)
> ```
>
> My idea was to set a route on "LOCAL-PC" like this:
>
> route add 10.0.200.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.11.0.8

> so I can simply connect to TARGET of CLIENT 2. If I need to connect to another TARGET I simply change my route.
>
> I have no idea how to solve that when my VPN-SERVER has to decide
> which TARGET I want to reach. Any idea how to solve that problem?

**EDIT 2:**

> As every attempt failed I gave up and switched to a TAP-Tunnel.
> Still I don't know how to setup the route correctly? I don't want to brige the complete interfaces (TAP <-> LAN). I only want a route so I can reach this one particular target.

Comment: Unless VPN_CLIENT is the default gateway of TARGET (and TARGET does not have direct route that conflicts with the VPN IP subnet), you'll at least need a "return route" for the VPN subnet on TARGET or source NAT set up for the VPN subnet on VPN_CLIENT.

Comment: VPN_CLIENT is the default gateway of TARGET, so I won't need a specific return-route.

Comment: Is it really a TAP VPN? Or is it a TUN one? Also, was ping the only thing you tried? (I mean, just in case firewall on TARGET blocks that.)

Comment: It is definitely a TAP adapter. I also tried to reach a webinterface on target so it is not a ICMP problem...
Strange thing is that this works:
> On my client I have two physical ethernet-adapter, one of which TARGET is conencted. When I connect to the other adapter, the IP-rounting works, and I can reach my target from adapter 2, but not via my openVPN client (tap-interface)

Comment: EDIT: I checked my openVPN-config and it says "dev tun" but windows shows a "tap-adapter"

Comment: ok, I rechecked. I is definitely TUN not TAP. Actually it seems there is no real TUN-Adapter in Windows, so it always shows "TAP-Adapter"...
> Anyway, what does that mean for my problem?

Answer (score 0):

To use a client as a gateway in the case of TUN vpn you need to configure `iroute` in the corresponding ccd file so that the vpn server process knows which client the traffics should be forwarded to, because no Ethernet framing is involved / "virtualized".

For traffics L3-destined at a client, it knows because there's like an implicit `iroute` configured for the client's VPN IP, which is why you can't configure arbitrary static IP on a VPN client instead of using what is pushed to you.

While route on a TUN VPN client might seem to be added as an indirect route with a nexthop / gateway, it's bogus. There's is nothing "extra" like the Ethernet frame header in the TAP VPN case that can carry the nexthop. (Certainly there's no ARP involved either.)

Comment: Thank you Tom, that makes sense.
But when you say the vpn-server is responsible for the routing I run into a problem:
This is a dublicate-client, so there are hundreds of clients out there with the same certificate.

In detail: The VPN-CLIENT is a machine and TARGET is a PLC connect to the machine-PC.
The PLC has the same IP on all of our machines. And all machines share the same client-certificate.

Comment: Any idea how I can solve the problem (see my edited post).
I still don't know how I can create a route form my LOCAL-PC to several TARGET with the same IP.

Comment: @mts If what you mean is you do not want `iroute` but instead, want the gateway to be configurable on the source host, then logically I don't see what else you can do other than making the VPN a TAP one. (I am not experienced with it so I'm just assuming everything would work like Ethernet in that case.) I mean, certainly you can set up multiple TUN VPNs as well, in which case you can have an iroute for the same destination(s) in each of the server, but then obviously it would be really clumsy (and even more so if you don't **just** the VPN(s) for this designated purpose).

Comment: @mts It's really the nature of every L3/TUN VPN: the nexthop is determined on the server, so at best you can for each possible nexthop desired, set up a dedicated tunnel for it.

Comment: Does the openvpn-server use the systems iptables?
So what happens if I create a route to the vpn-client on my server?

In this case I could route from my LOCAL-PC to the vpn-server which would forward to the client-ip.

Comment: It has nothing to do with iptables (not even with the "system" routes, as long as you are using `client-to-client`). What I mentioned in my answer is `iroute`. It's a client-specific config option on the server (again, as I mentioned, you'd want to research on ccd, client config directory) that tells the server which client should traffics of certain destinations should go to if the destination IP is not a client VPN IP (and not the server one either, of course).

Comment: @mts In "typical" setup where no `iroute` has been configured, such traffics get out of the tunnel interface on the server, which may hence be L3 forwarded by the server OS. (Therefore, if you have a system route on the server that routes such traffics into the tunnel again, you'll be creating some sort of loop.)

Comment: @mts If what you mean is that you *want* to apply iptables filtering for traffics forwarded from one client to another (made happen by an `iroute`), IIRC it is possible, and the way is **not** to use `client-to-client`, in which case all traffics will "escape" from the tunnel first anyway, i.e., the `iroute`(s) will be in effect if the traffics are routed into the tunnel again (with a system route) on the server. (I faintly remember there's some pitfall you might need to be aware of in such setup. Not sure what or if my memory is correct though.)

Comment: @mts Actually I wasn't recalling LOCAL-PC is not a client but a LAN "neighbor" of the server. In that case, you need both a system route and an `iroute` for traffics from it that you would like to go to a client. (Without an `iroute` the loop I mentioned would be created.) Again assuming you are talking about TUN VPN, it doesn't matter what nexthop / gateway address you set in the system route, the server process won't even receive that address. (It gets silently ignored at OS level, because there's no Ethernet frame or ARP whatsoever over TUN VPN.)

Comment: ok, I gave up... I switched from TUN to TAB and connection is working. What about the routing now? How do I reach my target?

Comment: @mts Not sure what you mean. What do you mean by working if you are not reaching your target? (I suggest that you start a new question with what's "working" and what's not since we are in a whole different story with TAP VPN, and we are not supposed to abuse the commenting feature further.)